# Create profile issue - Twilio CLI on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: authentication, twilio, command-line-interface

Installation of twilio cli finishes without any errors. However on trying to login to the cli I am facing this error.

```
twilio login
 » Secure credential storage failed to load.

Alternatively, twilio-cli can use credentials stored in environment variables:

# OPTION 1 (recommended)
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=your Account SID from twil.io/console
export TWILIO_API_KEY=an API Key created at twil.io/get-api-key
export TWILIO_API_SECRET=the secret for the API Key

# OPTION 2
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=your Account SID from twil.io/console
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=your Auth Token from twil.io/console

Once these environment variables are set, a twilio-cli profile is not required and you may skip the "login" step.
```

Now the environment variables are set successfully. On running the command echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID I am able to see the result.

Other details:
node -v
v14.16.0

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Step1 :
Twilio CLI was installed using the global tag.

Step2:

```
npm run deploy:twilio-cli
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  249.22 KB  build/static/js/2.adfce53b.chunk.js
  25.59 KB   build/static/js/main.312818aa.chunk.js
  745 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.ff852d00.js
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /rooms/.
https://cra.link/deployment
 » Could not find profile.
 » To create the profile, run:

  twilio profiles:create
```

Step3 : Ran the command  -

```
twilio profiles:create
 » Secure credential storage failed to load.
```

I have set the twilio credentials using export in the bashrc file to ensure they are loaded on every start.

Please help. Why does twilio need a profile and login if the env variables are set? How can I successfully deploy the app without facing the issue of having to create a profile?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
sudo apt install npm
npm install -g twilio-cli
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-dev
npm install -g @oclif/plugin-commands
npm install -g oclif
twilio plugins:install @twilio-labs/plugin-rtc
npm ci (install from package-lock.json)
npm run deploy:twilio-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bypass `twilio login` by following the steps here.

[Want to use environment variables instead of creating a profile?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/general-usage#want-to-use-environment-variables-instead-of-creating-a-profile)

Comment: I have gone through this doc before and have set the environment variables to bypass Twilio login. The problem is when I try to deploy the app it looks for a profile and then gives an error. I am following the steps shared here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react.

Comment: Probably best to open a Twilio support ticket via the console or help@twilio.com referencing this issue as discussed above.